# Getting specific data from a field which contains more than one data

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this column `ACTIVITY_SUB_ID` in an Oracle table that contains data like this:

```
(95!25145!01/01/2015)
```

Now, what I need is to extract say for example the date only or the `95` only or `25145` only.

How could I do that?

Comment: I don't work with oracle databases that much but maybe you could use regex (regexp_substr in oracle) to extract the number? Which oracle version do you use?

Comment: You can use regexp_substr(ACTIVITY_SUB_ID,'[^!]+', 1, 1)
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle extract variable number from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514189/oracle-extract-variable-number-from-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
select ltrim(regexp_substr('(95!25145!01/01/2015)','[^!]+', 1, 1),'(') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Split by `!`

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(ACTIVITY_SUB_ID, ')'), '('), '[^!]+', 1, LEVEL) AS parts FROM test
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(LTRIM(RTRIM(ACTIVITY_SUB_ID, ')'), '('), '[^!]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6bfad/1)